# Always running same Tab Android

Tags: java, android

I have a class where I create three tabs Tab.

The code is as follows

```java
public class Tab extends TabActivity{
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedinstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedinstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String idReunion = bundle.getString("idReunion");
        String nombreProyecto = bundle.getString("nombre_proyecto");

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;
        Resources res = getResources();

        intent = new Intent();

        intent.putExtra("idReunion", idReunion);
        intent.putExtra("nombre_proyecto",nombreProyecto);

        intent.setClass(this, PestanaSinAsignar.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Pestaña 1").setIndicator("Sin asignar").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent.putExtra("idReunion", idReunion);
        intent.putExtra("nombre_proyecto",nombreProyecto);

        intent.setClass(this, PestanaAsignadas.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Pestaña 2").setIndicator("Asignadas").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent.putExtra("idReunion", idReunion);
        intent.putExtra("nombre_proyecto",nombreProyecto);

        intent.setClass(this, PestanaAsignadaOtros.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Pestaña 3").setIndicator("AsignadasUsuarios").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I click in the tab two or three always executes code PestanaAsignadaOtros class which  is the class associated with the tab three.

It would be logical that when you press the tab two run PestanaAsignadas class code and if I click the tab three run the class code AsignadaOtros Pestana.

Why always running PestanaAsignadaOtros code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create different intents for each tab, currently you are trying to use the same intent for three different purposes:

```java
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

// First Tab
TabSpec firstspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("List");
// setting Title for the Tab
listspec.setIndicator("List View");

Intent firstIntent = new Intent(this, AddressActivity.class);
firstIntent.putExtra("Position", position);
firstspec.setContent(firstIntent );

// Second Tab
TabSpec secondspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Map");
secondspec.setIndicator("Map View");

Intent secondIntent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
secondIntent.putExtra("Position", position);
secondspec.setContent(secondIntent );


TabSpec thirdspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third");
thirdspec.setIndicator("Third View");

Intent thirdIntent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
thirdIntent.putExtra("Position", position);
thirdspec.setContent(thirdIntent );


// Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
tabHost.addTab(firstspec); // First tab
tabHost.addTab(secondspec); // Second tab
tabHost.addTab(thirdspec); // Third Tab
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the same intent for all 3 tabs. The changes you make to the intent after calling setContent will still happen. Instead you should create 3 intents, set their properties like you do above, and add them with setContent.